# How to find number of variables in a monomial in Maple?

Tags: math-software, maple

Given a monomial $m$. How to find number of variables in $m$ in Maple? For example, let $m=2*x*x$. Then the output to be $2$ (two same variable $x$ in $m$). Let $m=-2*x*y*y$. The output is $3$ (variables are $x, x, y$). How could we do this in Maple? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

degree() will work.  [Documentation](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=degree).

Answer (score 0):

How about this? - if the monomial is m then

> for v in indets(m) do m:=subs(v=_newvar,m): od:
>   ans:=diff(m,_newvar)*_newvar/m;